# Gate 4.0 installation issues with windows 10

Tags: java, gate

I am trying to install Gate 4.0 on my Windows 10 operating system. I am getting this error:

> [image: error]

I have jdk installed with 1.7 version following screen shot shows 
the version I have set the JAVA_HOME, path and CLASSPATH.

> [image: screen shot]

Note that I have installed Gate 8.1 and it worked fine with me but I need gate 4.0 to launch text2Onto.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to `launch4j` part not able to deal with the new java.
Try to run it directly - without the `.exe` file:

```
cd gate-4.0
java -jar lib/ant-launcher.jar run
```

See also following thread from the mailing list about how to "repair" java records in windows registry so `launch4j` can find your java:
https://sourceforge.net/p/gate/mailman/message/35472420/